# please I don't understand the second and third line of the code below

Tags: javascript

I saw this in someones code and i'm trying to understand what it means

```
 if(output=="" && history!=""){
            if(isNaN(history[history.length-1])){
                history = history.substr(0, history.length-1);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Take a tour on the MDN site, search about `isNaN()` and `substr()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'history' is an Array

the secound line is checking if the last item of 'history' array is not a number, if so, the third line deletes the last item in  the array

Comment: oh yeah that's true, thanks